# How to replace a string ending with _i with a string starting with i_?

Tags: bash

For example:

```
input   [TOTAL_CH-1:0]      start_frame_i,  // start of frame
```

Change to:

```
input   [TOTAL_CH-1:0]      i_start_frame,  // start of frame
```

Add on to clarify: There are many different strings are like above.

Comment: There are many of different string end with _i.

Comment: More efficiently using a built-in *parameter expansion* if `var="input   [TOTAL_CH-1:0]      i_start_frame"`, then you can do `var="i_${var/_i/}"`.

Comment: Can you show your work so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU sed.

```bash
cat file.txt | sed -r 's/(\w+)_i\b/i_\1/g'
```

`(\w+)_i\b`

- `(\w+)_i` matches one or more word character ending with `_i` and save the string before the `_i` inside a capturing group`(\w+)`. `\b` word boundary to ensure it is the end of a word and not to match something like `start_frame_iAAA` which will result in `i_start_frameAAA`

`i_\1` replace the matched string with, `i_` at the beginning and `\1` the value which we saved previously inside the capturing group.

Comment: This depends on GNU sed. Most other variants do not support class shortcuts like `\w` and `\b`. Also, the `-r` option is not universal. If you provide a platform-specific answer to a question that did not specify a platform, it's good to point out the limited scope of the answer.

Comment: I would argue that more important than a basic solution to this one problem is growing StackOverflow such that future visitors gain wisdom and solutions regardless of their platform. Your answer will continue to highlight your knowledge and wisdom perhaps for years to come, long after the OP has lost interest in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pretend that your `bash` tag means that interested in a solution that uses bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
        while [[ $line =~ ^(.* )(([a-z_]+)_i)([^a-z_].*)$ ]]; do
                line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}i_${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
        done
        echo "$line"
done
```

This script walks through stdin reading lines. For each line, it tries to find your source pattern using a bracketed regular expression. Bash stores the bracked subexpressions to the array `BASH_REMATCH`, so for each time we find it, we reassemble that line. When all replacements are done, we print the line.

You could do the same thing with sed, which is not part of bash but availabe as a tool almost everywhere:

```
sed 's/\([a-z][a-z_]*\)_i\([^a-z_].*\)/i_\1\2/g' input.txt
```

This avoids the `-r` or `-E` for ERE, which is not portable. BRE regexes are a little more clunky, but have more widespread support, especially in standard tools like sed.